# Samsung Smart TV, PlayDRM and HLS

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, drm, samsung-smart-tv, smooth-streaming

We use in our applications for Samsung Smart TVs either the Apple HLS or progressive download for getting/playing the video. We would like to move to the DRM protected content and we saw in the SDK documentation that the PlayReady DRM is supported Samsung Smart TVs.

What we do not understand is what kind of protocol we can use? Does the PlayReady DRM on 2011 and 2012 models (SDK 2.5 and 3.0) support only **Microsoft Smooth Streaming** or it is compatible also with the **Apple HLS**?

What kind of streaming protocol we need to use in order to be able to protect the content by DRM Samsung Smart TVs?

Any information, experiences are highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Not too much actually... I have gone through it of course, but I did not find anything about HLS there => usually this does not mean it is not supported, since the documentation is not too detailed and based on example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically (but there are exceptions) HLS does not support PlayReady, so the (by far) most likely protocol on the Samsung 3.0 SDK to support PlayReady is ASF, i.e. progressive-downloaded WMV streams.

However, the 3.0 SDK also supports MPEG-DASH and the HTTP Adaptive Streaming (HAS) protocol. MPEG-DASH, per se, does allow for PlayReady protection of A/V payloads. However, I do not know the Samsung SDK enough to say whether this is supported.

Comment: Hi, There is the SDK 2.5. SDK documentation: bit.ly/ApHUwe - To me it looks as only ASF is supported - can I ask you to look on it? Where did you found the SDK 3.0 PlayReady details. I went through the http://www.samsungdforum.com/ docoumentation and I have found only references to the SDK 2.5...

Comment: My bad, in fact I didn't realize it's only in the 2.5 docs. And indeed Samsung seems to confirm it's only in 2011 TV models (http://bit.ly/AATBst; see also doc at that link). From the looks of it, indeed only ASF seems to be supported.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help - I think also that it is really only ASF, what is supported.